# In a gallery of images,whenever I click on a image display with fullscreen and it should contain a button with 'X' that brings back to gallery

Tags: javascript, css, image, sass, fullscreen

I am unable to display the image on fullscreen and can't get back to gallery images. Is it possible to do this with Javascript.I tried many ways to display the image with full screen but I wasn't successful, I can display the image on the same page, but can't display with fullscreen. How to display with fullscreen and how can I include a button to get back to my gallery. I came across many solutions with jquery. Is it can be done with Js?? Please help me with this question.

**index.html**

```
<div class="image-gallery-items">
      <div class="image-gallery-item">
          <a href="#"
          class="thumbnail">
          <img  src="images/img.png"
          onclick="imgDisplay(this);">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="image-gallery-item">
        <a href="" class="thumbnail">
          <img
            src="images/img1.png" onclick="imgDisplay(this);">
        </a>
      </div>
</div>
 <div class="container">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times</span>
      <img id="fullImg" >
    </div>
```

**index.css**

```
.image-gallery-items{
display: flex;
margin:auto 0px;
flex-wrap: wrap;
overflow: auto;
clear: both;
overflow:scroll;
@include clearfloats;
   }

.image-gallery-item{
        float:left;
        position: relative;

    .thumbnail{
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        .closebtn{
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 15px;
            color: white;
            font-size: 35px;
            cursor: pointer;
            }
        img{
        width: 190px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 5px;
          }
       }
    }
  .container{
 position: relative;
     }
  #fullImg{
     width:100%;
    height:100%;
    object-fit: cover;
        }
```

**index.js**

```
function imgDisplay(img){

var fullImg=document.getElementById('fullImg');
fullImg.src=img.src;
fullImg.style.display="block";
```

}

Comment: Please Greeshma, post preprocessed CSS so your code runs out of the box [reprex].

Comment: Made changes.Will do it from next time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work on all devices but I hope this steers you in the right direction : https://codepen.io/ActiveCodex/pen/qBbRGPR (I couldn't get it to work using the built in code snippet).

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("container");

function imgDisplay(img) {
    var fullImg = document.getElementById("fullImg");
    fullImg.src = img.getAttribute("data-src-lg");
    openFullscreen();
}

function openFullscreen() {
    elem.style.display = "flex";
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        /* Firefox */
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
        elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
        /* IE/Edge */
        elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
}

function imgHide() {
    elem.style.display = "none";
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
    }
}
```

```css
.image-gallery-items {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto 0px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: auto;
  clear: both;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.image-gallery-items:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.image-gallery-item {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.image-gallery-item .thumbnail {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-gallery-item img {
  width: 190px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

#container {
  align-items: center;
  background: #333;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#container img {
  position: absolute;
  /* Change to 'cover' to fill the space */
  object-fit: contain;
  /* Remove 'max-' to fill the space*/
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#container .closebtn {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#container .closebtn:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-gallery-items">
  <div class="image-gallery-item">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x150" data-src-lg="http://placehold.it/1920x1090" onclick="imgDisplay(this);">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="image-gallery-item">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x140" data-src-lg="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" onclick="imgDisplay(this);">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <span onclick="imgHide();" class="closebtn">&times</span>
  <img id="fullImg">
</div>
```

[Source] https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen.asp

Comment: With this code,the image is not displaying with full screen. The code which I posted is doing is similar to the one you wrote.

Comment: My bad, how about this one. Added 'data-src-lg' attribute to reference your large image, or else it will impact your page load, as it will try to load all the large images.

Comment: Hi. If you mean the 'fullscreen' you get when maximising a YouTube video and takes over your whole screen, not sure this is possible with just JS.

Comment: Okay. Thank you:)

Comment: Hi @GreeshmaNimmala, I might have been wrong, is this what you're looking for? See example using the codepen link above.

Comment: If this comment/answer or any other one solved your issue, please upvote/mark it as accepted :)

Comment: The link you have shared is does the functionality for videos, my issue is regarding a ImageGallery where when user wants to open a image, it should display in fullscreen.